# radiobutton checked validation

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, radio-button

I have multiple panels and on each panel I have 2 RadioButtons. I need a way to check if a radiobutton has not been selected within each panel. If the panel contains 2 radiobuttons during a loop and if those 2 radiobuttons are not selected the variable (submit) would then be set to false.

Here is my code so far -

```
        foreach(Panel panels in groupBox2.Controls)
        {
            foreach (RadioButton radio in panels.Controls)
            {
                if (!radio.Checked)
                {
                    submit = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think the question needs to be clarified a little. What do the 2 checkboxes have to do with radiobuttons? Do you have multiple groups of radiobuttons per panel? What possibilities are there aside from just one radiobutton being checked?

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. It's very confusing.

Comment: Sorry typo I meant radiobutton not checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default each panel will only contain one radio checked it the radio buttons `AutoCheck` is true, Anyway to your question:

```
foreach(Control parent in groupBox2.Controls)
{
    Panel panel = parent as Panel;
    if (panel != null)
    {
        foreach (Control child in panel.Controls)
        {
            RadioBox radio = child as RadioBox;
            if (radio != null)
            {
                if (!radio.Checked)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(radio.ToString());
                    break;//if AutoCheck of all radio buttons seted to true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in one specific radiobutton, it would be easier to keep a global reference to it. That way you can just check the button directly whenever you'd like, rather than go through multiple loops.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work because the Container.Controls collection contains "Control" references, so you need to check each control to see if it's the type you're looking for.

```
foreach(var control1 in groupBox2.Controls)         
{             
    if (control is Panel)
    {
        foreach (var control2 in control1.Controls)             
        {
            if (control2 is RadioButton)
            {
                if (!(control2 as RadioButton).Checked)                
                {                     
                     MessageBox.Show(control2.Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That will make your current code work. But I'm not quite sure what you're asking. There can only be one radiobutton selected in each containter.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!radM.Checked && !radF.Checked)
{
    lblAnswer.Text = "Please Select male or female";
    txtHT.Text = null;
}
```